# GetElementById("ex").value = " in ( 51,52,53)" ERROR

Tags: vba, getelementbyid

I'm a regular user of VBA on excel but in one case when I'm trying to select a value from a drop-down on a website its value is "in ( 51,52,53)" and when I try to use it the drop-downs becomes blank.
On the same ID if I use another value say "not in (1,2,3)" it works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: No code or HTML source in your post, so how could we help?

Comment: ^^ And include the url if public.